# Eclipse Erro: Intializing Java Tooling

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Quando inicio a ide do Eclipse é apresentado o erro Initializing Java Tooling. Como corrigir isso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta o comando no cmd assim `c:\ecplise\eclipse.exe -clean` (troque c:\eclipse pela pasta da sua instalação)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é um dos seus projetos que está causando o problema provavelmente, terá que identificar, um deles que esta causando o erro `java.lang.NullPointerException`, este erro é muito generico, pode ser qualquer coisa que você fez, mas geralmente é quando tenta passar uma variável null para um método especifico, tipo tentar usar `File` e passar `null` no nome do arquivo.

Pode tentar o "modo limpo":

```
c:\ecplise\eclipse.exe -clean
```

Ainda sim recomendo que analise todos seus projetos, ou uma *lib* ou um deles deve estar causando a mensagem.